# Concatenate two cells together on an import query

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am hoping to concatenate on a query

The following code works:

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A2:Y20, "SELECT A, D, I where C < 3",1)
```

and I want to concatenate A and D ... making the code something like this:

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A2:Y20, "SELECT A AND D, I where C < 3",1)
```

So A and D are in the same cell, and I is in the cell next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet1!A2:A20&Sheet1!D2:D20, Sheet1!I2:I20, Sheet1!C2:C20}, 
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col3 < 3", 1))
```

Comment: @Bradie fixed. try now

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
=filter({Sheet1!A2:A20&Sheet1!D2:D20, Sheet1!I2:I20}, Sheet1!C2:C20<3)
```

Comment: Does not work for all, as I have a where in some queries. I have edited the post